# Easy BI : Calculate cumulative total on text field

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

I am very new to Easy BI.
In the below snapshot, you can see each issue with overall efforts in decimal. But when I try to get it based on type, I am not getting a cumulative total. Let me know what the issue may be.
Also, if the field is text how to convert to number?

[image]